# What formula will tell me how many comparisons I will need to make to generate a rank order?

Tags: algorithms, sorting

I have a list of 278 songs by the Beatles. How many distinct comparisons of songs (Song A vs Song B) will I need to make until I have a rank order? (Let's say it is not necessary to compare EVERY song with each other, which we could work out fairly easily.)

I was hoping for a formula a non-mathematically-minded person could actually use (e.g. something that could be popped in a spreadsheet).

I'm not sure of the best way to do this, but I was imagining giving each song a point for every comparison it 'wins'.

Comment: Do a web search for "sorting algorithms". The best ones will make something like $278\log278$ comparisons.

Comment: Do you actually want to generate this rank order, or do you just want to know how many comparisons it would take to generate it?

Comment: Michael, I'm curious as to how many I'm going to need to make. I don't want to generate a random rank order, but look at how many comparisons I'll need to make.